# Attaching Dynamic Variable in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a problem attaching a dynamic variable when Im using find method in ES6. Pls check my code below. I need to attached the productValue. Is this not possible?

```
const productValue = 1;

products.find((item => item.option[productValue] === 'food'))
```

Comment: Can you include ``products`` in your question

Comment: @Majed Badawi. products is just an array

Comment: This is not attaching right. You are checking if `item[i][1]` is equal to food. Please add some sample data and expected output to clear this.

Comment: I guess you need to include sample of products array

Comment: @Tushar Shahi. just editon my question. basically i want to attach 1 to the variable item.option so it would something like orange1

Comment: `products` is array of object or array of string?

Comment: @Alireza Ahmadi. array

Comment: @Joseph So, If I understand correctly, you want to append `1` i.e., `productValue` to the `option`?

Comment: @Nithish. yes append it to the variable name

Comment: @Joseph please show your input array and your expected output, it's unclear what exactly you're trying to do without this information

Comment: @Nick Parsons. I just want to append the productValue to the variable of item.option. For instance. if variable name of item.option is food then I it would be food1

Comment: what is option`? you said that it is array of string!!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not correct usage of find in array. Look at the sample:

```js
products = ["vegetable", "food", "test"];
const productValue = 1;

var res = products.find((item => console.log(item)));
```

Now look at this one:

```js
products = ["vegetable", "food", "test"];
const productValue = 1;

var res = products.find((item => console.log(item[1])));
```

See you are using `"vegetable"[1]` that is first character of each string

You know the index so easily check in if `products[productValue] == "food";` Or of you want find by index use `findIndex`.

**Upadte**

After chattin with OP I understand he wants to append the `productValue` to one of products key value (`option` that is string), so you need to use `+` operator:

```
products.find((item => (item.option + productValue) === 'food'))
```

Comment: Im not finding or adding the index. I just want to append the productValue to item.option

Comment: You said that products is array of string! Ok you have array of object that one of keys is options? right?

Comment: yes options is a key

Comment: @Joseph OK you want to add productValue  to all options of your array? Also show the input and output of your question to make sense

Comment: This is already right.products.find((item => item.option === 'food')). I just want to append it to `item.option` key

Comment: option is string? or number?

Comment: string. the key i want not the value of `item.option`. append it to the key

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235255/discussion-between-alireza-ahmadi-and-joseph).

Comment: Still not working work?

Comment: @Joseph what do you mean by not working? you can concat string with number like that: `like "food" + 1 --> "food1"`

Comment: This one (item.option + productValue) . value is undefined

Comment: show me the value of `products` it has option key?  what is value of option?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the index parameter to check whether a specific item in an array equals some value.

sample:

```js
const productValue = 1;
const products = ['beverages', 'food'];
console.log(products.find((item, index) => index === productValue && item === 'food'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const products = ["vegetable", "food", "test"];
const productValue = 1;

const updatedFruits = products.map(product => {
  if(product === "food"){
    return product + productValue
  }
  return product;
});

console.log(updatedFruits)
```